# Which decks on the Enterprise-D are least likely to get damaged?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I'm interested to know what deck(s) are the safest, or least likely to suffer damaged during an attack/crash?

Has anyone ever done an analysis on which decks (in the TNG TV canon) receive the most and least damage?

[image]

Comment: Why  the downvote?

Comment: I don't understand the question. When the Enterprise was made, all decks were  undamaged. When the Enterprise belly-flopped on a planet, all decks were damaged. Can you please explain what you're looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Memory Alpha [article](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701-D%29) on the Enterprise D mentions these deck damages:

- [Q Who](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q_Who_%28episode%29): Decks 4,5,6 had sections removed.
- [Best of Both Worlds](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds_%28episode%29): Heavy damage, decks 23-25 ([part 2](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds,_Part_II_%28episode%29)), 36 mentioned explicitly.
- [Generations](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations): Ship destroyed.

**What deck(s) are the safest, or least damaged?**
According to [this](http://www.ussenterprise.co.uk/enterprise/entd/entddeck.htm), decks 1-16 are on the saucer section. Decks 4-6 had *issues* in Q Who, so the safest would be 1-3, 7-16 as tho crashed, the saucer section did land relatively ok on Veridian III.